# Python - Sqlite3 - Select query with database double dot operator

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I'm trying to pull a SELECT query from within the python 3.6.5 code using sqlite3 in PyCharm. 
The query has the double dot operator. Here is a sample code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sqlite3
connection = sqlite3.connect('ddbserver')
c = connection.cursor()
sql_query = """ select * from database..tablename  """
res = c.execute(sql_query)
```

When I run the script, it throws the following error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near ".": syntax error
```

The same query runs fine on SQL Server Management Studio, as well as in an xml file.

I've tried using the full path to the table as well i.e.

```
select * from database.schemaname.tablename
```

But it throws the same error.

Any sort of help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What is a "double dot" operator supposed to do? That's obviously not valid syntax for sqlite.

Comment: `database.schemaname.tablename` is also not valid sqlite syntax, btw.

Comment: the double dot operator pulls the default schema for a table.
I'm relatively new to this sqlite3. I use the double dot in the SSMS in routine so I copied the same query into the string